# Streetview into fragment android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, google-street-view

I need to add the streetview into a fragment

```
public class Streetview extends Fragment  implements OnStreetViewPanoramaReadyCallback {
WebView wv1;
SupportMapFragment mSupportMapFragment;
private GoogleMap googleMap;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_streetview, container, false);
    StreetViewPanoramaFragment streetViewPanoramaFragment =
            (StreetViewPanoramaFragment) getFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.streetviewpanorama);
    streetViewPanoramaFragment.getStreetViewPanoramaAsync(this);
    return view;
}
@Override
public void onStreetViewPanoramaReady(StreetViewPanorama panorama) {
    panorama.setPosition(new LatLng(-33.87365, 151.20689));
} }
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/streetview

I tried that but its not working

How to add streetview to a fragment in android?

Comment: "but its not working" is not a question. Please describe in more detail what **is** happening instead

Comment: @cricket_007 How to add a street view to fragment

Comment: Yes, that's your question, but what is not working with this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're in a Fragment, already, so you can use a [`StreetViewPanoramaView`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/StreetViewPanoramaView) in your XML, not another Fragment.

In the link you posted, [there are examples of that class](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/master/ApiDemos/app/src/main/java/com/example/mapdemo/StreetViewPanoramaViewDemoActivity.java)

I would suggest using that instead.

---

`StreetViewPanoramaFragment` already is a Fragment,  so you ideally should not have it inside another one. You instead should use it directly from the Activity, like your link shows.

If you did want that, though, a Fragment in another Fragment, needs to be gotten from the `getChildFragmentManager()`. No guarantees that works, though.

Comment: I got error `inconvertable type android.support.v4.app.Fragment to com.google.android.gms.maps.StreetviewpanoramaFragment` @cricket_007

Comment: Its a fragment so i extended fragment class. Which class i need to extend @cricket_007

Comment: I've given an alternative answer to the problem, but basically `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` is not the same as `android.app.Fragment`

Comment: How to fix that issue?

Comment: Please refresh the page to see my updated answer. Just don't use the Fragment class for the street view

Comment: If i remove the Extended class Fragment How can i use it as a fragment?

Comment: No no. You can extend Fragment. That is fine. You instead should use the View class, as described for the Street view

Comment: Literally from the link you already posted. Just convert that to a Fragment https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/master/ApiDemos/app/src/main/java/com/example/mapdemo/StreetViewPanoramaViewDemoActivity.java

Comment: `  switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    Property_list tab1 = new Property_list();
                    return tab1;
                case 1:
                    Nearby tab2 = new Nearby();
                    return tab2;`

Comment: ` case 2:
                    Streetview tab3 = new Streetview();
                    return tab3;
                case 3:
                    Similar tab4 = new Similar();
                    return tab4;

                default:
                    return null;
            
     }`

Comment: Please do not post code in the comments. I know it does use an Activity. It also uses `StreetViewPanoramaView`. Please forget about the Activity / Fragment differences and use that View object in your own code following the example given

Comment: i got incompactable type required android...panoramaview found android view